# [myView isKindOfClass:[UIView class]] giving weird result

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I have UITableViewCell where I am adding an `UIView` and inside it, I am adding subviews as `UIButton`, `UIImageView`.

Now I wanted to access UIView in `willDisplayCell`. For that I have below.

```
NSArray *subviews;
subviews = cell.subviews;

int xxyyzz = 1;
for(id aView in subviews) {
    NSLog(@"aView====%@" , [UIView class]);
    if([aView isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
        NSLog(@"This is UIView... Do what you want to do...");
    }
}
```

However when I run, I am getting `This is UIView... Do what you want to do...` for all subviews (i.e. for UIButton, UIImageView, etc). `aView====UIView`

**I believe this is because, UIView is superclass of all objects.**

### Is there way where I can access only UIView that I have inside  `UITableViewCell`...

Comment: are you looking for this cell.contentView.subviews?

Comment: @Shoaib : NO, I just want UIView that I have created...

Comment: You get that because all views are a subclass of UIView.  What did you expect?  If you want a view you created, the obvious thing is to hold onto a pointer to it (in a custom cell class).  Otherwise you can tag the view and check the tag, but you need to be sure the tag doesn't conflict with another.

Comment: @HotLicks : yes, I got the problem and solution too...

Comment: @Downvoter : details for downvote please..

Comment: For not reading the documentation.

Comment: @HotLicks : then I would say I think you didn't read my statement **I believe this is because, UIView is superclass of all objects.**. Any way, downvote is not big deal... I love to have it... :)

Comment: That's not the only documentation you didn't read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not getting totally you problem, but probably there is a misunderstanding in the use of the method `-isKindOfClass`. Particularly that method respond YES for classes and subclassess, `UIButton`,`UITableView` etc are subclasses of `UIView` so the method is working as expected, here the documentation:

> Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the receiver is an
>   instance of given class or an instance of any class that inherits from
>   that class.

Most probably you want to use `-isMemberOfClass` that consider only if the object is an instance of a specific class.

You must also pay attention using that method if the object you are inspecting comes from a class cluster, for instance `NSArray`, quoting Apple documentation:

> Be careful when using this method on objects represented by a class
>   cluster. Because of the nature of class clusters, the object you get
>   back may not always be the type you expected. If you call a method
>   that returns a class cluster, the exact type returned by the method is
>   the best indicator of what you can do with that object. For example,
>   if a method returns a pointer to an NSArray object, you should not use
>   this method to see if the array is mutable, as shown in the following
>   code:

```
// DO NOT DO THIS! if ([myArray isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]])
{
    // Modify the object 
}
```

> If you use such constructs in your code, you might think it is alright
>   to modify an object that in reality
>   should not be modified. Doing so might then create problems for other
>   code that expected the object to remain unchanged.
>
> If the receiver is a class object, this method returns YES if aClass
>   is a Class object of the same type, NO otherwise.

Comment: You got my problem... the reason was `UIButton,UITableView etc are subclasses of UIView`. Check my answer for solution...

Answer (score 0):

What I did is I created custom UIView as below.

```
 MyCustomView *mview = [[MyCustomView alloc] initWithFrame:...
```

and then added UIButton, UIImageView inside this custom view.

Now while comparing, I checked it as below.

```
if([aView isKindOfClass:[MyCustomView class]]) {
```